# Get IP from argv fail

Tags: python, argv, gethostbyname

I'm trying to get the ip address of a website given from args. When I try with the website directly in the source code like 'url='https://google.com' it works but when I try with 'url = sys.argv[1]' it fails.

When I print the 'url = sys.argv[1]' I get the desired website. I tried to str(url) it but it doesn't work neither.

Here's the code :

```
import socket
import sys

# Params
url = sys.argv[1]
# url = str(sys.argv[1])

print (type(url))   # I get the desired url

s = socket.socket()

# Get IP
ip = socket.gethostbyname(url)

# Print Infos
print ('IP Adress : ' + ip + '\n' + 15*'-')

s.close()
```

Do you have any idea?

Thank you, it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you're passing in the `https//:`; you need to remove it:

```
In [3]: ip = socket.gethostbyname("http://google.com")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-7466d856e904> in <module>()
----> 1 ip = socket.gethostbyname("http://google.com")
```

Instead, try:

```
In [4]: ip = socket.gethostbyname("google.com")

In [5]: ip
Out[5]: '172.217.25.238'
```

Note that you'll also want to remove any trailing slashes, for example, remove `/` in `google.com/`.

If you look at `man gethostbyname` you'll see that you're making a DNS request:

> The `gethostbyname()` function returns a structure of type hostent for the given host name.  Here name is  either a hostname or an IPv4 address in standard dot notation (as for `inet_addr(3)`).

So, you need to make sure you cleanup anything you pass to that function call.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying for like 2 hours to make it running and just removing the 'http' from args does the job.

It was fast !

Comment: it's done! Thank you for your time. You saved my life today haha